# Why does /var/lock/tt-rss keep being deleted after reboot?

Tags: files, directory

I use `sudo mkdir /var/lock/tt-rss/` to create this folder which a program called *tiny rss* needs. But if I reboot Ubuntu, the `lock` and `tt-rss` folders no longer exist. It's as if Ubuntu is treating them like temp folders.

I need `/var/lock/tt-rss/` to be a permanent folder. How can I make it stay? I could probably do a startup entry, but that seems more of a workaround than a fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Oneiric, `/var/lock` is a symlink to `/run/lock`:

```
$ ls -ld /var/lock
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Jan 15 18:30 /var/lock -> /run/lock
```

`/run` and `/run/lock` are tmpfs filesystems:

```
$ mount | grep /run
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
```

In other words, your files are not stored on your root filesystem, but are lost at every reboot *by design*.

Files in `/{var,run}/lock` are not meant to be long-term storage locations. To solve your problem, you can create a script that creates `/var/lock/tt-rss/` at every boot, and maybe that backups its content at every shutdown (depending on your needs). However this probably deserves an another question.

Comment: Thank you. I made a startup script (bash) in init.d to make the folder. I used this guide: http://jonathonhill.net/2009-04-23/auto-start-a-shell-script-on-ubuntu-server/